# linking a cell in a userform

Tags: cells

I have a user form that posts scores to a person's file. The way it works is the person starts by entering their name and then answers a series of 13 questions. The UserForm is attached to TestingFile1 and once they are finished they click a button and it "posts" the results to their file Example X:rep testing\2018 reps\SchJ.xlms (The test file is located in a different directory) the cell I would like to link to takes all the results and shows an average. The data goes to the rep but the form goes to the rep's supervisor. I would like to add a box on the testing form that once the rep enters their name, based on the name it would show their current average in the form (this would be before the current test. That current cell in the Reps file that holds the running average is o26.
 Having never tried this before this is what I currently have but it's not going to work.

```
  Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
  If CSRep.Text = "Alyssa Vangundy" Then
  Textbox1.Text = X:\Audit Tracking\Reps\2018 Reps\[VanA.xlsx]VanA'!O26
  End Sub
```